# Calculus of variations when functional involves inverse of the function

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

Typically the Euler-Lagrange equations are defined for the functional

$$ J[u] = \int_a^b L(x,u,u') dx. $$

However, I was wondering if anyone knows if they can be solved when the expression involves the inverse of $u$? The way my problem is formulated, it is simplest to write as

$$ J[u] = \int_{u^{-1}(a)}^{u^{-1}(b)} L(x,u,u') dx, $$

but it could equivalently be written

$$ J[u] = \int_{u(a)}^{u(b)}L(x,u,u^{-1},u') dx $$

I had a bit of a play with it and I have a feeling it is not generally solvable, but I'm really just playing -- not an expert in this area.

Cheers!

EDIT:

To make it more clear why this situation might arise, consider a distribution with pdf $g(x,\vec{\theta})$, but for which the variates are measured with some uncertainty (i.e. the "observed" distribution is a convolution of the original with the uncertainty distribution of the variates). Whether we can directly calculate the convolution or not, since it preserves number density (between different limits), it can be parameterised as a function $\hat{u}(x)$.

Now consider a hierarchical likelihood model which aims to recover the original underlying distribution. Such a likelihood may look like this:

$$ \ln\mathcal{L} = \sum \ln g(x_i) + \ln P(x_i|\hat{x_i})$$

where the $x$ are (hyper-)parameters and the $\hat{x}$ are the observed variates including uncertainty, and $P$ is the uncertainty distribution. Let's call the conversion from estimated to observed $u$, i.e. $\hat{x} = u(x)$ (so that if $u$ = $\hat{u}$ we recover the initial distribution). In the continuous limit, the likelihood should look like

$$ \ln \mathcal{L} = \int_{u^{-1}(x_0)}^{u^{-1}(x_1)} \frac{g(\hat{u}^{-1}(u(x)),\tilde{\vec{\theta}})}{d\hat{u}/d\tilde{x}} \left[ \ln g(m,\vec{\theta}) + \ln P(m|u(m))\right] dx $$

(I think I have all my jacobian adjustments etc. right here -- oh, and tilde represents original input parameters). Thus you can see the inverse in the limits. If instead I defined $u$ the other way around, so that $x = u(\hat{x})$, then the limits have $u$ but the integrand itself has $u^{-1}$.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: By "inverse" $u^{-1}$, do you mean $u(u^{-1}(x)) = x$ or $u(x) u^{-1}(x) = 1$?

Comment: Ah, good point. I meant the former.

Comment: It looks hard, since you need to invert $u + \varepsilon \varphi$...

Comment: Yeah, that's why I thought it might actually be impossible in a general sense. But you never know what some clever mathematician has come up with...

Comment: For me the question does not look very "natural". The functional inverse of $u: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$  is not meant to be integrated over the same domain as $u$. Do you have an application in mind?

Comment: Yes, a very specific application -- I guess it may turn out that I have constructed the problem incorrectly, but I don't think so. I'll edit the question with more details as to the nature of the problem

Comment: One could try introducing the inverse via a Lagrange multiplier, i.e. add a constraint $f(u(x))-x=0$, where $f$ will be the inverse. This is perhaps in the end equivalent to Robert's suggestion

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I have solved it, and it doesn't require the inverse after all. @Robert 's answer led me to the solution by showing that I could construct the integral from a to b rather than some function of $u$ or its inverse. Once in that space, it is not too hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, the best thing to do would be to write $x = f(u)$ and then use
$$
\int_{u^{-1}(a)}^{u^{-1}(b)} L(x,u,u') dx = \int_a^b L\left(f(u),u,\frac{1}{f'(u)}\right)f'(u)\ du
= \int_a^b M\left(u,f(u),f'(u)\right)\ du
$$
and now compute the Euler-Lagrange equation for $M$, which will give you the differential equation you want to solve for the function $f$.

Comment: This is correct, though it took me a while to make sure of it :) In fact, if I had approached the problem in a better way initially then I would have gotten to this result without all the inverses.

Comment: @StevenMurray:  Ah!  Isn't that the way it always is; hindsight is always clearer!